# Add/Remove Class with jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, function

I have this code.

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none; 
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<br />
<div class="slidingDiv">
    Fill this space with really interesting content.
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Someone tell me if its possible to add in this jquery function that if i click on it, at the same time to show/hide a new div, change a class to an  tag and remove another class from another  tag? How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the tags related in any way hierarchically? If so, yes. If not, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**remove**: `jQuery('element').removeClass('class');` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
**add**: `jQuery('element').addClass('class');` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) 
And you can use toggleClass to switch.
**toggle**: `jQuery('element').toggleClass('class otherClass');` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, but how can i apply this one to a specific menu>li>id="name" ?? Like this? $('#menu li name').removeClass('classname'); Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

yes you can, take a look of the method [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and also of the [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: ... and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), and [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) in general :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, but how can i apply this one to a specific menu>li>id="name" ?? Like this? $('#menu li name').removeClass('classname'); Thanks.

Comment: open a new Question and asked for that doubt that you have

Answer (score 3):

Add class:

```
$('selector').addClass('className');
```

Remove class:

```
$('selector').removeClass('className');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, but how can i apply this one to a specific menu>li>id="name" ?? Like this? $('#menu li name').removeClass('classname'); Thanks.

Comment: just use the name attribute as selector. $("name=['the name']")

Answer (score 1):

yes of course you can add or remove classes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#ButtonId").click(function () {
    $('#itemid').removeClass('classname');
    $('#itemid').addClass('classname');
});
</script>
```