# How to add active class to div in a nav list using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have three div's as a `nav` list. I want to add active class to a div when clicked. Below is my code but it is not working properly. Please help me to fix it out.

html

```js
function changeClass() {
    var divsLenght = $(".list").children().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < divsLenght; i++) { 
      $('.list').children(i).toggleClass('tabActive item');
    } 
    $(this).addClass('tabActive');  
}
```

```css
.item
{
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #f8f9fa;      
}

.tabActive{
  background: #87ceeb69;
  border-left: 3px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" onclick="changeClass(this)">
    <center><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br>Students</center>
  </div>
  <div class="tabActive" onclick="changeClass(this)">
    <center><i class="fas fa-book"></i><br/>Lesson Plan</center>            
  </div>
  <div class="item" onclick="changeClass(this)">
    <center><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><br/>Settings</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no explict `this` in an `onclick` function.  You are passing in `this` in html but not using it in the script code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add/Remove Class with jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658077/add-remove-class-with-jquery-function)

Answer (score 2):

Updated your code to achieve the same with Jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.item').click(function(){
    $('.item').removeClass('tabActive');
    $(this).addClass('tabActive');
  });
});
```

```css
.item
{
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: #f8f9fa;        
}

.tabActive{
    background: #87ceeb69;
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
    <div class="item">
        <center><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br>Students</center>
    </div>
    <div class="item tabActive">
        <center><i class="fas fa-book"></i><br/>Lesson Plan</center>            
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <center><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><br/>Settings</center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is easy and understandable.

Comment: Please do mark the answer as accepted so that it helps other community members as well who are looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html

```
<div class="list">
<div class="item" >
    <center><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br>Students</center>
</div>
<div class="item" >
    <center><i class="fas fa-book"></i><br/>Lesson Plan</center>            
</div>
<div class="item" >
    <center><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><br/>Settings</center>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item").click(function(){
$('.item').removeClass('tabActive'); 
$(this).addClass('tabActive'); 
});
});
```

Comment: please add explanation how and why it works

Comment: You need to learn JQuery 's class operating

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .item
        {
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            background: #f8f9fa;        
        }

        .tabActive{
            background: #87ceeb69;
            border-left: 3px solid blue;
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
            <center><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br>Students</center>
        </div>
        <div class="item tabActive">
            <center><i class="fas fa-book"></i><br/>Lesson Plan</center>            
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <center><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><br/>Settings</center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div.item').click(function(){
                // for more information about removeClass() -> https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
                $('div.item').removeClass('tabActive');
               // for more information about addClass() -> https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/
                $(this).addClass('tabActive');
            });
        }); 
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```